# How to part out an existing codebase to git submodules

Tags: git, dependencies, repository, git-submodules

I am in the process of converting all of my old usable code into git repositories.  This is both a tactical and strategic question.

So I have created a new blank repo on Github called HomeBase (it is private right now).  I then did a `git clone` to pull this blank repo to my local.

I then copied in all the files from my "Home Base" PHP project for a client into that folder, cleaned it up some, committed it using SourceTree, and pushed to master on Github.

Now, I want to take certain subfolders in the project (which are used identically in several projects), and turn them into submodules and independent git repos (again, they are used identically by other projects so they are basically 'third party libraries').  The subfolders contain anything from PHP utility tools to javascript libraries.

My question is how to remove these subfolders from the HomeBase repo, create new repos and populate with the respective files, and then re-link them to the HomeBase repo.  I need and appreciate help with both specific steps as well as strategy on this.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. If you found the answer helpful please use the uptick option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your question requires following several steps:

1. remove subfolders: `git rm -r subfolder_name`
2. go to [Create a New Repository](https://github.com/new)

and create the separate repositories you would like. You can then add the files to this repository from GitHub (easier learning curve). If you would like to do it from CLI (Command Line Interface) run the following:

2.a Run the following code from a directory that you wish to make a repostiory

```
git init
git add *
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repo_name.git
git push -u origin master
```

3. Go to your HomeBase repo that will store the other git submodules and run `git submodule add <path_to_other_repos>"` and voila, you should have the submodules you desire that have a link to the other repositories.